# Thymeleaf Spring Security Dialect didnt work

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a home page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
                xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wellcome</h1>
    <sec:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <h4>You have all possibilities!</h4>
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <h1>You are login</h1>
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
        <h1>You are not login</h1>
    </sec:authorize>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <spring.version>5.3.14</spring.version>
        <security.version>5.3.13.RELEASE</security.version>
    </properties>

    <name>lab_6 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("org.example.lab_6")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new
                SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

 
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

}
```

After I log in, log in and get to the main page, I see absolutely all messages, although this should not be the case. It seems to me that sec tags are not working, although I configured them correctly. What can be wrong. I have authorization and authentication configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<sec:authorize` is for the deprecated JSP taglib.

Try using `<div sec:authorize` as shown in https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html.

Why not upgrading to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.1.2.RELEASE?

You can also get rid of the xmlns:sec attribute in the html tag, is it's configured by `addDialect`.